# Math for max and min x and y of an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, maxima-minima

I see that the general equation of an ellipse centered at the origin is:

(+)² + (+)² = ²

How do a, b, c, d relate to the coefficients of the general form?

A² + B + C² + D + E + F = 0

After some naive observation I believe:

A = (² + ²)
   B = 2( + )
   C = (² + ²)
   F = -²

Pretty sure it's more complicated than that. The issue for me is to do the calculations based on numerical values for an ellipse in either standard or canonical form, as opposed to pencil and paper derivatives.

Comment: have an example $21x^2-6xy+29y^2+6x-58y+151=0$

Comment: OK, so using that example, F is an imaginary number. Also, I'm trying to go from the general form (with the capital letters) and get to a, b, c, d, and r.

Comment: I misrepresented my question from the very first line! Basically, I have an ellipse that is not necessarily centered at the origin and possibly rotated. I have either the standard form (or the canonical form as it is derivable) and I am trying to find the max and min x and y.

Answer (score 1):

$$(ax+by)^2+(cx+dy)^2=r^2\\
a^2x^2+2abxy+b^2y^2+c^2x^2+2cdxy+d^2y^2=r^2\\
(a^2+c^2)x^2+(2ab+2cd)xy+(b^2+d^2)y^2-r^2=0\\
\therefore A=a^2+c^2B=2(ab+cd),C=(b^2+d^2),D=E=0,F=-r^2$$

Comment: This is what the OP wrote...

Comment: How do i convert it into $21x^2-6xy+29y^2+6x-58y+151=0$ standard form, I mean $pX^2+qY^2=1$ form

Comment: @PeterForeman The OP also said he thought it was more complicated than that. This answers the question, as I read it, and proves that it is not more complicated than that.

Comment: Thanks, that IS how I got to the equivalencies I posted. But I have an equation where D and E are not 0. That's where I suspected there might be more to it. I would be surprised if I could simply ignore D and E but if someone actually verified that, I would accept it.

Comment: @TJSartain If $D$ and $E$ are not zero, then you therefore are dealing with something other than an ellipse centred at the origin.

Comment: @Théophile Correct. In my case the ellipse can be centered anywhere and arbitrarily rotated. I see now that in my original post I was quoting a situation like you astutely noticed. This makes me feel less than bright at the moment and I need to maybe repost somehow.

Comment: @TJSartain No worries. :) You might find the Wikipedia article on the [general form of an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse) helpful. From that page you can see that you can extract the centre of the ellipse from the relationship between $A,B,C,D$, and $E$.